# How can i display sublevel TableView using the Different Arrays by customizing Sections and rows

Tags: ios

I want to display the data in a way like this in my TableVIew. I have 3 sets of arrays

1. Category Arrays
2. Album Arrays
3. Track Arrays

Category1 may contains many Albums and each Album contains many tracks ....
Category2 may contains many Albums and each Album contains many tracks ....

how can i configure the section and rows in my tableView. Any one give me an idea how can i do it

1. **CATEGORY 1**

   ***ALBUM1***

   *Track 1*

   *Track 2*

   ***ALBUM2***

   *Track 1*

   *Track 2*
2. **CATEGORY 2**

   ***ALBUM1***

   *Track 1*

   *Track 2*

.... and son on

[Clik here to see my TableView Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHjgM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method to expand/collapse, and use the methods `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to show/remove the subcategories. Then you don't need sections.